# Programmatically retrieve a list of a user's Facebook pages

Tags: api, facebook

Greetings,

Using the Facebook API, I have obtained an OAuth access token for a user. I can use it to retrieve information about the user and post to their wall, etc. I'm trying to figure out how to (or if there is a way to) programmatically get a list of pages a user owns (so that they can be presented in a drop-down list on a third-party site). I have been unable to find such a method in the Facebook API, but I'm hoping I've missed something.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you searched the Facebook Developer forums?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this question was asked, Facebook has added a new connection on the "User" Graph API object: `accounts`.

> The Facebook pages owned by the
>   current user. If the manage_pages
>   permission has been granted, this
>   connection also yields access_tokens
>   that can be used to query the Graph
>   API on behalf of the page. <sup>[Graph API Reference: User](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user)</sup>